# Python lambda self composing function: How to return a function that is repeated n amount of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, iteration

A function `self_compose(x,y)` takes as argument a callable statement `x` and an integer `y`.

This function then returns another callable function, of which is the result of 
having `x` call itself `y` times 
i.e.

```
sc = self_compose (lambda x : x*3, 3) # => ( ( (x*3) * 3) *3 )

sc(2) # = 54
```

The question is how do I create a lambda within a lambda without having to use recursion?

Comment: Why do you think either of those things is necessary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As to why having what things? The lambdas? It was part of an assignment to understand how lambda works in conjunction with function arg grabbing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Readable Alternative

There really is no need for neither recursion or nested *lambdas*, you could simply define *`self_compose`* by having it create, and return, a function that simply calls the supplied *callback* `n` times.

```
def self_compose (cb, n): 
    def __worker (val):
        for _ in range (n):
            val = cb (val)
        return val 

    return __worker
```

```
sc = self_compose (lambda x: x*3, 3)

if sc(2) == 54:
  print ("SUCCESS")
```

```
SUCCESS
```

---

#### The *"I like one-liners"*

You could, of course, create it in one go by using something as the below:

```
from functools import partial, reduce
self_compose = lambda cb,n: partial (reduce, lambda v,cb: cb(v), [cb]*n)
```

```
if self_compose (lambda x: x+x, 3) ('B') == "BBBBBBBB":
   print ("SUCCESS")
```

```
SUCCESS
```

Comment: Oh dang it, that's what I didn't understand! I attempted to use a for loop that returns the callable function, but I didn't know how to implement it. I had a vague understanding as to how arguments were collected within a function!